# Evaluate the integral of a complex function over the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Question: Evaluate $\int_{\gamma}(z^{3}+3)$ $dz$ where $\gamma$ is the unit circle centered at the origin described in positive sense 
Is my approach right to this question okay?
 I should determine the points where the integrand is not analytic like looking for zeros in my denominator
 If this is correct then how do I set this up? I just learned this stuff and I only have notes on showing Cauchy Integral being analytic. Need help. 
 Update: On $\gamma$, if $z$=$e^{i\theta}$ then would that mean $dz$=$ie^{i\theta}$ $d\theta$ where $0\le \theta \lt 2\pi$
 but incorporating this into the Cauchy formula is still not getting to me.
 The formula is $f(z_0)$=$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_c \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}$ $dz$ 
 I am missing the key concept because I do not have a $z_0$ in my problem

Comment: Your aproach will work just fine, and it is the right approach for many problems in complex analysis but a more simple-minded substitution $z = e^{it}$ will work here, too.

Comment: Thanks but setting the problem up and showing that it works is confusing me right now. Somehow I got to use Cauchy Integral

Comment: I think you are describing a "path integral" around the unit circle centered at the origin in the complex plane, but your notation is somewhat non-standard.  Since the integrand is a polynomial, it appears that the integrand is analytic (and thus the integral around the circle is zero).  One worries, not about places where the integrand is zero, but about *singularities* of the integrand that happen to lie inside the closed path (contour).

Comment: @hardmath interesting, maybe I will learn that in the next class meeting. I have nothing on your approach to it to go off of

Comment: So then the exercise it demonstrating that path integral using the more simple minded substitution equal to the result when evaluating all of the singularities with Cauchy's Integral formula.

Comment: Have a look at the Wikipedia article on [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula) just to be sure we are on the same page.  (You will see there that there are various simpler and more complicated formulas that could be so called.)

Comment: We are on the same page as far as the theorem and proof sketch goes on the link

Comment: Said in a short way, if $f(z)$ is analytic (in particular if $f$ is a polynomial), $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=0$, whatever the closed contour $\gamma$.